# How to setOnclickListner for the intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I want to load the url (google.com) in myclass first. When click on any further link, it should be open in web_view.class.
How can I correctly set onclickListener to pass the intent? I'm new to android. I'll be very thankful for the help. Here is myclass.java code.

```
public class myclass extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webh);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                if (newProgress==100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        this.webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, web_view.class);
        String mUrl= "https:google.com";
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(mUrl));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you want to click on? I don't see any other views than the WebView and the ProgressBar.

Comment: First I want to load the url using webview in myclass. And when clicked on any link of it, it should be open in web_view class. For example, I want to load the first www.ebay.com (in myclass). And, when click on any products of ebay.com, my web_view activity should open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override `WebViewClient`.

```java
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, 
                WebResourceRequest request) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(myclass.this, web_view.class);
        intent.setData(request.getUrl());
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: get an error   intent = new Intent(this, web_view.class);
                         ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous WebViewClient> cannot be converted to String)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous WebViewClient> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Sorry I missed something. I updated the code. You need to reference `myclass.this` in the anonymous inner class.